# Multidimensional array over pipe C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, pipe

I have a struct looking like this:

```
struct result {
    int personId;
    int questionId;
    int choice;
};
```

And I'm trying to establish a 2-way comminucation between parent and child.
I have an array:

```
struct result finalResults[3][20];
```

And I'm sending this 2D array row-by-row through pipe like this(from child part):

```
write(p2[1], &finalResults[0], sizeof(finalResults[0]));
write(p2[1], &finalResults[1], sizeof(finalResults[1]));
write(p2[1], &finalResults[2], sizeof(finalResults[2]));
```

Then I'm trying to read it on the parent side:

```
    while ((n = read(p2[0], resultBuffer, sizeof(resultBuffer)) > 0)) {
           int i = 0;
           for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
           if (resultBuffer[i].choice != 0)
              printf("Result for question id: %d, person id: %d, choice: %d\n", resultBuffer[i].questionId, resultBuffer[i].personId, resultBuffer[i].choice);
}
```

Where resultBuffer is:

```
struct result resultBuffer[1024];
```

Well everything goes well, however the parent only reads the first line of the 2D array and not the rest.
What could be the problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: I think, you did not close file descriptior(your buffer  on file descriptior table after dup commands) after you write to buffer,if you don't close,procces don't understand input is finished or continued writting by procces to bufer until you close file descriptior  from table

Comment: Can it be that the parent code reading in values is entered only once when  the client writes the first line, and that this code is not entered any more when the client writes the other lines?

Comment: @FatihAltuntaş I close it immediately after writing like:
close(p1[0]);
close(p2[1]);

Comment: @StephanLechner no because I have a wait(&status); in the parent code, so it waits child to finish.

Comment: What's the value of `n`? The read will probably consume all the lines at once, but in your loop you access only 20 elements...

Comment: Why isn't the parent using the same shape of array as the child?  Or, alternatively, why isn't the protocol set up so that the shape of the array is properly identified as data sent over the pipe?  Also, why don't you just write: `write(p2[1], &finalResults[0][0], sizeof(finalResults));` with a single write rather than using multiple writes?

Comment: You should use the value in `n` to guide you about how many structures to print.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't paying attention to the number of bytes read by the parent, and you probably aren't closing the write end of the pipe quick enough.  Here's a minor variant on your code with those problems fixed:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct result {
    int personId;
    int questionId;
    int choice;
};

int main(void)
{
    int p2[2];

    pipe(p2);

    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(p2[0]);
        struct result finalResults[3][20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                finalResults[i][j].personId = rand() % 36 + 100;
                finalResults[i][j].questionId = rand() % 20 + 1;
                finalResults[i][j].choice = rand() % 5 + 1;
            }
        }

        printf("Child:\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                printf("(%d,%2d,%d)", finalResults[i][j].personId,
                       finalResults[i][j].questionId, finalResults[i][j].choice);
                if (j % 5 == 4)
                    putchar('\n');
            }
        }

        write(p2[1], &finalResults[0], sizeof(finalResults[0]));
        write(p2[1], &finalResults[1], sizeof(finalResults[1]));
        write(p2[1], &finalResults[2], sizeof(finalResults[2]));

        close(p2[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        struct result resultBuffer[1024];
        int n;
        close(p2[1]);
        while ((n = read(p2[0], resultBuffer, sizeof(resultBuffer))) > 0) {
            int n_entries = n / sizeof(resultBuffer[0]);
            printf("Read: %d entries\n", n_entries);
            for (int i = 0; i < n_entries; ++i) {
                if (resultBuffer[i].choice != 0)
                    printf("Result for question id: %2d, person id: %d, choice: %d\n",
                           resultBuffer[i].questionId, resultBuffer[i].personId,
                           resultBuffer[i].choice);
            }
        }
        close(p2[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This populates the entire 60-element 2D array with values, uses your long-winded triple-`write()` to send the information to the parent process, and prints the initialized array — the three calls could be reduced to one:

```
write(p2[1], finalResults, sizeof(finalResults));
```

Note that there is no call to `srand()` so the output will be the same each time.  You can arrange varying seeds with in a number of ways.

Sample output:

```
Child:
(131,10,4)(102,11,3)(124,19,4)(101, 1,1)(124, 3,3)
(111, 8,5)(116,13,4)(101,10,3)(104,14,5)(118,17,1)
(125, 7,3)(119,11,4)(119,10,5)(121, 8,3)(101,17,1)
(129, 9,2)(106,18,2)(129, 9,5)(128,11,5)(108,11,4)
(134, 7,5)(108, 2,4)(109, 9,4)(125,19,2)(107,14,1)
(122, 4,2)(105,10,1)(134,10,2)(129,16,1)(108,12,4)
(112, 4,1)(134,13,2)(116,18,4)(100, 2,3)(111, 9,3)
(126,18,3)(130, 5,5)(111, 6,1)(103,19,3)(107, 9,3)
(100,18,5)(128,16,4)(105,11,2)(106, 3,1)(122,13,3)
(109,16,3)(115, 2,1)(115,19,3)(128,11,1)(131,16,2)
(108,19,1)(103,15,4)(125, 1,1)(106, 4,2)(129,11,4)
(110, 1,5)(134,15,2)(106, 4,4)(128,11,1)(127, 4,3)
Read: 60 entries
Result for question id: 10, person id: 131, choice: 4
Result for question id: 11, person id: 102, choice: 3
Result for question id: 19, person id: 124, choice: 4
Result for question id:  1, person id: 101, choice: 1
Result for question id:  3, person id: 124, choice: 3
Result for question id:  8, person id: 111, choice: 5
Result for question id: 13, person id: 116, choice: 4
Result for question id: 10, person id: 101, choice: 3
Result for question id: 14, person id: 104, choice: 5
Result for question id: 17, person id: 118, choice: 1
Result for question id:  7, person id: 125, choice: 3
Result for question id: 11, person id: 119, choice: 4
Result for question id: 10, person id: 119, choice: 5
Result for question id:  8, person id: 121, choice: 3
Result for question id: 17, person id: 101, choice: 1
Result for question id:  9, person id: 129, choice: 2
Result for question id: 18, person id: 106, choice: 2
Result for question id:  9, person id: 129, choice: 5
Result for question id: 11, person id: 128, choice: 5
Result for question id: 11, person id: 108, choice: 4
Result for question id:  7, person id: 134, choice: 5
Result for question id:  2, person id: 108, choice: 4
Result for question id:  9, person id: 109, choice: 4
Result for question id: 19, person id: 125, choice: 2
Result for question id: 14, person id: 107, choice: 1
Result for question id:  4, person id: 122, choice: 2
Result for question id: 10, person id: 105, choice: 1
Result for question id: 10, person id: 134, choice: 2
Result for question id: 16, person id: 129, choice: 1
Result for question id: 12, person id: 108, choice: 4
Result for question id:  4, person id: 112, choice: 1
Result for question id: 13, person id: 134, choice: 2
Result for question id: 18, person id: 116, choice: 4
Result for question id:  2, person id: 100, choice: 3
Result for question id:  9, person id: 111, choice: 3
Result for question id: 18, person id: 126, choice: 3
Result for question id:  5, person id: 130, choice: 5
Result for question id:  6, person id: 111, choice: 1
Result for question id: 19, person id: 103, choice: 3
Result for question id:  9, person id: 107, choice: 3
Result for question id: 18, person id: 100, choice: 5
Result for question id: 16, person id: 128, choice: 4
Result for question id: 11, person id: 105, choice: 2
Result for question id:  3, person id: 106, choice: 1
Result for question id: 13, person id: 122, choice: 3
Result for question id: 16, person id: 109, choice: 3
Result for question id:  2, person id: 115, choice: 1
Result for question id: 19, person id: 115, choice: 3
Result for question id: 11, person id: 128, choice: 1
Result for question id: 16, person id: 131, choice: 2
Result for question id: 19, person id: 108, choice: 1
Result for question id: 15, person id: 103, choice: 4
Result for question id:  1, person id: 125, choice: 1
Result for question id:  4, person id: 106, choice: 2
Result for question id: 11, person id: 129, choice: 4
Result for question id:  1, person id: 110, choice: 5
Result for question id: 15, person id: 134, choice: 2
Result for question id:  4, person id: 106, choice: 4
Result for question id: 11, person id: 128, choice: 1
Result for question id:  4, person id: 127, choice: 3
```